# Optional caption in listings (for listoflistings)

Tags: table-of-contents, listings, captions

I have some cites in my captions. But I do not want to appear them in the table of figures or listings.
With figures I managed to display an different caption like this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.55\linewidth]{images/FIPA_Message-Transport-Reference-Model}
  \caption[FIPA Message Transport Reference Model]{FIPA Message Transport Reference Model (\cite{FIPA2000}).}
  \label{fig:FIPA_Message-Transport-Reference-Model}
\end{figure}
```

But with lstlisting I have some troubles because the caption is an option of the listings and that seems not to have an optional caption label.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[ language=Scala,
label={lst:Publisher},
caption={Publisher notify\cite{Zenger2013}}] 
  protected def publish(event: Evt) {
    filters.keys.foreach(sub =>
      if (!suspended.contains(sub) && filters.entryExists(sub, p => p(event)))
        sub.notify(self, event)
    )
  }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Any Ideas how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is covered in Section 4.9 of the [`listings`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/listings) documentation; you can use

```
caption={[short caption]long caption}
```

Here's a complete MWE to demonstrate:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\begin{lstlisting}[ 
label={lst:Publisher},
caption={[caption for lol]Publisher notify\cite{Zenger2013}}] 
  protected def publish(event: Evt) {
    filters.keys.foreach(sub =>
      if (!suspended.contains(sub) && filters.entryExists(sub, p => p(event)))
        sub.notify(self, event)
    )
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```